# Xamarin Forms Post Request Http Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, http-post, dotnet-httpclient

I'm working on making a POST request using my Xamarin form to send data to an Action in my controller in my WebAPI project. The code with breakpoints doesn't go beyond

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("192.168.79.119:10000");
```

I have namespace System.Net.Http and using System mentioned in the code.

```
 private void BtnSubmitClicked(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> statCode = ResetPassword();
        App.Log(string.Format("Status Code", statCode));


    }
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ResetPassword()
    {
        ForgotPassword model = new ForgotPassword();
        model.Email = Email.Text;
        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("192.168.79.119:10000");

        var content = new StringContent(
           JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Email = Email.Text }));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/api/api/Account/PasswordReset", content); //the Address is correct

        return response;
    }
```

Need a way to make a Post request to that Action and sending that String or the `Model.Email` as a parameter.

Comment: are you sure it's not throwing an exception?  Try adding a scheme ("http://") to the URI string

Comment: That seemed to help! But it still won't Post.

Comment: but what is the issue? Do you have exception, some message, etc.??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a proper Uri and also `await` the Task being returned from the called method.

```
private async void BtnSubmitClicked(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
    HttpResponseMessage response = await ResetPasswordAsync();
    App.Log(string.Format("Status Code: {0}", response.StatusCode));
}

public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ResetPasswordAsync() {
    var model = new ForgotPassword() {
        Email = Email.Text
    };
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.79.119:10000");
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    var content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var path = "api/api/Account/PasswordReset";
    return client.PostAsync(path, content); //the Address is correct
}
```